# WCS.all_pix2world: Read in latitude and longitude of entire FITS field

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have FITS file in pixel coordinates. I want to basically read in its latitude and longitude.

I know we can use something following:

---

```
from astropy import WCS 
w = WCS('sample.fits') 
lat, long = w.all_pix2world(90, 38, 1)
```

But instead of one RA(=90), DEC(=38) value inside

```
w.all_pix2world
```

I want to fetch latitudes and longitudes (in Galactic coordinate system) of the entire field of *sample.fits*.

```
header  
NAXIS = 2  
NAXIS1 = 150  
NAXIS2 = 150
```

---

Please let me know if any other information is needed. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please *answer* the question yourself, instead of stating "solved". Or close or remove the question altogether. Now you're letting anyone else who stumbles upon this and has the same question, in the dark how to solve this.

Comment: Note that there is also an [astropy] tag.

Comment: @9769953 Thanks. I am going to upload the solution code to my git-hub and then post it here. Does it look okay?